# Find the boundary, the closure and the interior of the following sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, vector-analysis

Find the boundary, the closure and the interior of the following sets:

$$F = \{ (x,y) \in R^2 : (x^2+y^2-1)(4-x^2-y^2) >0\}$$
$$G = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 :  x + y + z < 1\}$$
$$H = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 :  x + y + z < 1, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0\}$$

As there's no possible graphical representation of some of them, I'm completely lost. Could you tell me how to start or any reference to consult?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Show that $F = \{ (x,y) \in R^2 : (x^2+y^2-1)(4-x^2-y^2) >0\}= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: 1<x^2+y^2<4\}.$   (annulus, draw a picture !).
2. For $F = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 :  x + y + z < 1\}$ think about $\{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 :  x + y + z = 1\}  $ a plane !
3. For $F = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 :  x + y + z < 1, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0\}$ consult 2. and the first octant.

Comment: For the first case, what changes do you do on the expression to have $1<x^2+y^2<4$ ?

Comment: For a product of nambers $a$ and $b$ we have: $ab>0 \iff a,b >0 $ or $a,b <0.$